# Data Masking on Autonomous Database (ADB)?

Tags: masking, data-masking, oracle-autonomous-db

What are the Data Masking options on ADB. The Oracle documentation seems to mention restrictions is Data Masking:

https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/paas/autonomous-database/adbsa/appendix-restrictions-database-features.html#GUID-B6FB5EFC-4828-43F4-BA63-72DA74FFDB87

List of Removed Oracle Features - Oracle Data Masking and Subsetting Pack

Answer (score 1):

Data Safe is the tool that goes alongside Autonomous Database to help with data masking and auditing features. Read more about implementing Data Safe here:

https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/paas/data-safe/udscs/get-started-oracle-data-safe.html

*Ref - I am a product manager on the Oracle Autonomous Database*